# Transpose Data Frame with Column and Row names intact in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to do a simple transpose function by keeping the column names in the first row and the first rows in the column name. Similar to Excel.

The code I wrote is:

```
Book1 <- read_excel("C:/X/X/X- X/X/Book1.xlsx")
dput(Book1)
X1 <- as.data.frame(t(Book1)) 
X2 <- transpose(Book1)
```

Both of these outputs are in such a manner that the either the column names or row names are excluded in the output.

Attached is the dataframe I am working with which is "Book1" is shown below:

```
structure(list(`Row Labels` = structure(c(1667260800, 1669852800, 
1672531200, 1675209600, 1677628800, 1680307200, 1682899200, 1685577600, 
1688169600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    X1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), X2 = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
    3, 2, 3, 2), X3 = c(3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3), X6 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), X7 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), X8 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), X9 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

The expected output is:

[image]

Can someone let me know what is it that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After transposing a dataframe with `data.frame(t(Book1))`, you can use the `rownames_to_column` function from the `tibble` package and the `row_to_names` function from the `janitor` package.

```
data.frame(t(Book1)) %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```r
setNames(as.data.frame(t(Book1[-1])), Book1[[1]])
```

output

```r
   2022-11-01 2022-12-01 2023-01-01 2023-02-01 2023-03-01 2023-04-01 2023-05-01 2023-06-01 2023-07-01
X1          1          2          2          3          3          4          4          5          5
X2          2          3          2          3          2          3          2          3          2
X3          3          4          3          4          3          4          3          4          3
X6          1          1          1          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA
X7          1          1          1          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA
X8          1          1          1          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA
X9          1          1          1          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

Add `tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "Row Labels")` to it if you want rownames to be a column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a custom function to transpose `data.frame`s. It can definitely be improved, at the moment it just works with a numeric selector of id columns default is always the first column (in the future I want to add tidy select syntax):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

tdf <- function(df, id = 1, transform_nms = NULL, idcol_nm = NULL) {

  stopifnot(is.numeric(id))
  
  tmp <- df[, -id]
  
  if(is.null(idcol_nm)) idcol_nm <- names(df[,id])
  
  if(!is.null(transform_nms)) {
    col_nms <- transform_nms(df[[id]])
  } else {
    col_nms <- df[[id]]
  }
  new_col_nms <- c(idcol_nm, col_nms)
  
  out <- as.data.frame(t(tmp)) %>% rownames_to_column()
  names(out) <- new_col_nms
  
  out
}


tdf(Book1, transform_nms = \(x) as.character(x))
#>   Row Labels 2022-11-01 2022-12-01 2023-01-01 2023-02-01 2023-03-01 2023-04-01
#> 1         X1          1          2          2          3          3          4
#> 2         X2          2          3          2          3          2          3
#> 3         X3          3          4          3          4          3          4
#> 4         X6          1          1          1          1          1         NA
#> 5         X7          1          1          1          1          1         NA
#> 6         X8          1          1          1          1          1         NA
#> 7         X9          1          1          1          1          1         NA
#>   2023-05-01 2023-06-01 2023-07-01
#> 1          4          5          5
#> 2          2          3          2
#> 3          3          4          3
#> 4         NA         NA         NA
#> 5         NA         NA         NA
#> 6         NA         NA         NA
#> 7         NA         NA         NA
```

Data from OP

```r
Book1 <- structure(list(`Row Labels` = structure(c(1667260800, 1669852800, 
                                          1672531200, 1675209600, 1677628800, 1680307200, 1682899200, 1685577600, 
                                          1688169600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               X1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), X2 = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
                                                         3, 2, 3, 2), X3 = c(3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3), X6 = c(1, 
                                                                                                                1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), X7 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                    NA, NA), X8 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), X9 = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(Book1)
```

**method 1 using data.table::transpose()**

```
X2 <- data.table::transpose(Book1, keep.names = "Row Labels", make.names = "Row Labels")
```

**method 2 using melt and dcast**

```
X2 <- setnames(dcast(melt(Book1, id.vars = "Row Labels"), variable ~ `Row Labels`), "variable", "Row Labels")
```

**results**

```
X2

   Row Labels 2022-11-01 2022-12-01 2023-01-01 2023-02-01 2023-03-01 2023-04-01 2023-05-01 2023-06-01 2023-07-01
1:         X1          1          2          2          3          3          4          4          5          5
2:         X2          2          3          2          3          2          3          2          3          2
3:         X3          3          4          3          4          3          4          3          4          3
4:         X6          1          1          1          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA
5:         X7          1          1          1          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA
6:         X8          1          1          1          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA
7:         X9          1          1          1          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA
```